# MVVMCross: Binding Two Way doesn't update viewmodel

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a property in a custom control in a Xamarin.Android project.

```
public class MyControl : RelativeLayout
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When MyProperty is updated in the ViewModel side, it updates fine the MyProperty in the View. However, nothing happens if I update the MyProperty in the View  (I'd like to get the updated value in the ViewModel).

**The binding:**

```
public class MyControlMyPropertyTargetBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private bool _subscribed;

    protected MyControl MyControl
    {
        get { return (MyControl)Target; }
    }


    public MyControlMyPropertyTargetBinding(MyControl target)
        : base(target)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var myControl = (MyControl)target;
        myControl.MyProperty = (ObservableCollection<string>)value;
    }


    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(ObservableCollection<string>); }
    }


    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
    }

    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        base.SubscribeToEvents();
        var myControl = MyControl;
        if (myControl == null || myControl.MyProperty == null)
            return;

        myControl.MyProperty.CollectionChanged += MyPropertyOnCollectionChanged;
        _subscribed = true;
    }

    private void MyPropertyOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        FireValueChanged(MyControl.MyProperty);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var myControl = MyControl;
            if (myControl != null && myControl.MyProperty!= null && _subscribed)
            {
                myControl.MyProperty.CollectionChanged -= MyPropertyOnCollectionChanged;
                _subscribed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Setup.cs:**

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<MyControl>("MyProperty", myProperty => new MyControlMyPropertyTargetBinding(myProperty));
}

protected override IList<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies
{
    get
    {
        var assemblies = base.AndroidViewAssemblies;
        assemblies.Add(typeof(MyControl).Assembly);
        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

**Update:** The same control binded on Windows Phone works two way perfectly. The control itself is into an external reference.

Does someone know what I missed?

**Edit 1:** I updated target binding with collection changed subscription but nothing's fired. The ObservableCollection is updated programatically by code, not by user input.

Comment: I don't see any code in `MyControlMyPropertyTargetBinding` which notifies the ViewModel when the `View` changes - e.g. see `SubscribeToEvents `in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding.cs#L64

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stuart. As suggested, I added event subscription but nothing's more fired. Same problem (only ViewModel > View binding works) if I bind it into the view with CreateBindingSet. Could it be because MyControl inherit from RelativeLayout and not from View?

Comment: Any other idea? I just can't understand why it works OneWay despite my TwoWay binding

Comment: `myControl.MyProperty.CollectionChanged` is not what's changing - you are changing the whole of `myControl.MyProperty` - so you need some kind of `myControl.MyPropertyChanged` event (if you had `public event EventHandler myControl.MyPropertyChanged;` then MvvmCross wouldn't even need a custom binding)